# Can I dump a DB2 database on an AS400 to Windows or Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, compatibility, db2-400

It's been years since I've worked with DB2, but I just inherited a legacy appllication that reads/writes to DB2 via JDBC and it runs on an AS400. I don't have a lot of details yet on the platform or versions, but I am wondering is it generally possible to migrate a copy of the DB to either Windows or Linux version of DB2?  The application accesses the data over a very slow pipe and I'd like to be able to cut a copy of the DB for local development. The JDBC driver used is:

```
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
```

If that helps...

Any/all replies are appreciated!

***Update: I just found out that DB2 version is 7.1 and the platform is iSeries (should I be asking for additional details regarding the platform?)***

~~ Cheers ~~

Comment: The first question I would ask is why move it? Are you planning on getting rid the the IBM i? Is there speed issues? Are you dropping support for that application?

Comment: It creates a dependency on the connection to the remote server, via a secured connection. The DB2 production instance is staying on the iSeries -- I just want to see if it is possible to move a copy of the test DB to a local server for higher productivity during development cycles....

Comment: Ask whether you are on Technology Refresh 4 ["v7.1 TR4"].  If so, you will be able to specify the server name [RDB Directory Entry] in a 3-part qualified name.  This would make things easier.

Comment: Thanks WarrenT! If the DB is R4, what would the basic process be for getting a cut running on a local dev box? Can you provide a basic outline or thoughts?

Comment: Any progress about that? I've run into the same issue (having an iSeries V5R4M0 production DB2, and thinking about having a local development copy on Windows/Linux machine)

Comment: Never approached it with the client.  We still may try to do so -- if you have any success please post here?

Answer (score 0):

If you install iSeries Navigator (Database component at the least), you can drill into the needed schema (or schemas) and select the option to 'Generate SQL' for the various object types that SQL recognizes. The SQL can then be ported to whatever DBMS you'll use.

Of course, that's separate from any data. And there's significant chance that numerous objects won't make any sense to any other platform. There's a small chance that the "database" won't make much sense on a different platform. It'll depend on how long the database has existed (it might predate SQL), how progressive the developers were over the years, how much advantage they took of platform-specific features, etc.